# AnimatePresence not working on Chrome but works fine on Firefox

Tags: framer-motion, react-animations

I am trying to implement a simple `fadeIn` animation for tab contents using `framer-motion`.

When I click on a tab I want to display contents of selected tab with a `fadeIn` effect, which is working as expected on `Firefox` but ***does not*** works on `Chrome`.

Below is my code

1. Animation Variant

```
const TAB_CONTENT_LOADING_VARIANTS = {
  fadeIn: {
    opacity: [0, 1],
    transition: {
      duration: 0.7,
      ease: 'easeIn'
    }
  }
};
```

2. Tabs code

```
<AnimatePresence>
  {
    tabState.selectedId === 'step-1' && (
      <TabPanel
        as={ motion.span }
        key="step-1"
        animate="fadeIn"
        variants={ TAB_CONTENT_LOADING_VARIANTS }
        { ...tabState }
      >
        ...Contents
      </TabPanel>
    )
  }
  {
    tabState.selectedId === 'step-2' && (
      <TabPanel
        as={ motion.span }
        key="step-2"
        animate="fadeIn"
        variants={ TAB_CONTENT_LOADING_VARIANTS }
        { ...tabState }
      >
        .... Contents
      </TabPanel>
    )
  }
</AnimatePresence>
```

I have checked for console logs but did not find any.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I am not sure why but changing `motion.span` to `motion.div` make it work!!!